# change a default jdbc driver class in Pentaho Data Integration tool

Tags: jdbc

I'm trying Pentaho data integration and I want to use MySql as my output RDBMS, but the default driver class used is org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver which is used for mm.mysql databases but I want to use the usual com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class to connect to mysql. I don't know how to change it or add a new driver. can any one help, please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem.
**Missing driver file.**
This error is really common for people just getting started with PDI.

1. Download MySQL JDBC Driver.
2. Copy the .jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.29) and paste it in your **Lib** folder:
   Windows: C:\Program Files\pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib
   OS X: /Applications/data-integration/lib
3. Restart Pentaho Data Integration and Test your connection.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

For the new version of the MySQL JDBC driver (in my case version 8.1), the name of the main driver class has changed. Even if you download the driver and restart spoon, still the MySQL connector of Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) looks for the wrong class name.

The workaround would be to use the "**Generic database**" connection type in PDI and add the new class name by hand. The typical connection details would be:

```
Dialect: MySQL 
Custom connection URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name 
Custom driver class name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Reference: https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-17341